# How to fix ERROR: Service failed to build: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: 18.04, apt, nvidia, docker

I'm trying to implement this computer vision
[github's repository](https://github.com/ahmetozlu/vehicle_counting_tensorflow#installation) and using  Ubuntu 18.04.1, but I am stuck. I installed nvidia-docker to setup the docker with Nvidia GPU. Thus, to run the demo in the GPU. After some troubles with dependencies finally I ended up with this error.

```
$ docker-compose up
```

```
Building vehicle_counting
Step 1/3 : FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.4.0-gpu-py3
 ---> c349ca9427dc
Step 2/3 : RUN apt update -y && apt install -y python3-dev libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev python3-tk
 ---> Running in 63e84d498e36
ERROR: Service 'vehicle_counting' failed to build: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

First, I ran `apt update -y && apt install -y python3-dev libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev python3-tk` as suggested by the `Step 2/3` and then ran `docker-compose up` again with no success.

Secondly, I tried to create an [image from alpine](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/beginners/building-docker-image-from-scratch.html) as suggested by this issue's [comment](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron/issues/180#issuecomment-464343304). However, could not fix it yet.

My `$ sudo docker info` output:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 6
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 6
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-42-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.465GiB
 Name: sutd-ThinkPad-T430
 ID: EPKL:3BDO:PPX2:6QN4:DM3R:KFHI:MD3K:NWEB:KXEH:BFP4:4YQZ:5RWW
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2736 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.3'

services:

  vehicle_counting:
    image: vehicle_counting
    container_name: vehicle_counting
    working_dir: /vehicle_counting
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
    command: python3 -u vehicle_detection_main.py
    volumes:
      - ./:/vehicle_counting
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    runtime: nvidia
```

`DockerFile`:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.4.0-gpu-py3

RUN apt update -y && apt install -y \
python3-dev \
libsm6 \
libxext6 \
libxrender-dev \
python3-tk

RUN pip3 install \
numpy \
opencv-python \
matplotlib
```

Any logs should I post, please let me know. Thanks in advance. Any suggestion of what I am doing wrong will be appreciated.